# How Do I Find Information on the Site about Working with Clients

Tags: discussion, faq

I want to know what are the do's and don'ts with client.

While we are going for the project discussion, while doing it and after doing it.

Simply before implementation and after implementation.

Comment: Hi @Sivajith, welcome to PMSE! Could you please share a bit more about your context like how do you work and what kind of relationship do you or will you have with your customer? I tagged some very good Q/As with the [customer tag](http://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/customer), have a look at them. They may answer your question.

Comment: hi, thanks for the link. i am working as SAP B1 Consultant.

Comment: I think the list on each side would be long.  If you can narrow it down to a topic or two, that would be helpful, e.g., "during planning," "managing risks," "under a firm fixed price contract."

Comment: Hi Sivajith, we're closing for now to hold off answers until you have a moment to add more details with an [edit] to your question. Please leave a comment once updated and we can look at reopening. Welcome to PMSE!! :)

Comment: Can you reframe your question with some specifics, so it's not just a request for a general list of best practices? Providing a specific goal and some context would be very helpful in generating good answers.

Answer (score 1):

see @Zsolt comment on searching the "customer" tag.